# How to start a new paragraph in a text field in firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to know if there is a way to format the text of a a text field in firestore with a word break using the firebase console. I would like for example to have result for example (text into 2 different lines or part of different paragraphs)

> The sun shine on us.
>
> This is a good news

Whatever text I add in firebase console, seem to default to a simple linear string (output is as follow)

> The sun shine on us. This is a good news

I am able to achieve this result by adding formatted text from my app to firestore hoever I would like to do it the same using the firebase console. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the answer provided by a developer from Firebase in this Github issue [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2366), it seems that  Firebase indeed, silently strips newlines (both on input and on output). For this reason, even using `\n`, for example, wouldn't work for you, as it doesn't support new lines or this kind of formatting.

I searched around and it seems that this is not reported, so feel free to report it in the [Firebase Issue Tracker](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/). So, for now, unfortunately, the only option seems to be using SDKs, as you are using in your application, to add data in a formatted way.

Comment: Firestore doesn't strip anything.  All text is preserved.  The console just collapses whitespace for readability (realistically, how you would render 1000 lines of text in the console?

Comment: Thanks gso_gabriel. It looks like you are right. There is no way to input line breaks from the firbase console